# How can I assign a string with quotes to a variable in bash, and use it as a pattern in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The command that I'm using is :

```
objects=shubham
awk -v myvar="$objects" '($0~myvar),/REPLACE/' a.txt
```

the a.txt file contains

```
other-unwanted-content-here
target(shubham)
hello('shubham')
abc
bcd
REPLACE
other-unwanted-content-here
```

My desired output is:

```
hello('shubham')
abc
bcd
REPLACE
```

...but I'm getting `target(shubham)` as well. How can I make `hello('shubham')` *with the quotes* be the place where awk starts matching?

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches, depending on what you want.

- Keep `objects` defined the way it is, amend your awk variable's assignment

  ```
  objects=shubham
  awk -v myvar="^hello[(]'$objects'[)]\$" '($0~myvar),/REPLACE/' <<'EOF'
  ```

  See this running at https://ideone.com/Bto1hB
- Change `objects` to match only the target line

  ```
  objects="^hello[(]'shubham'[)]\$"
  awk -v myvar="$objects" '($0~myvar),/REPLACE/' a.txt
  ```

  See this running at https://ideone.com/nF8MUl

Note that in either case, `~` in awk is a regex operator; since in most regex forms (including [POSIX ERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)) `(` and `)` are syntax, we had to change your string to be a regex that matches the desired line, instead of containing exactly that line itself. (Note that in both cases, the backslash before the `$` in the regex is shell syntax, not regex syntax itself, necessary only because we're in double quotes; in single quotes those backslashes would need to be left out).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I'd do a full string rather than partial regexp comparison for robustness and use a flag instead of a range expression for efficiency and ease of future changes:

```
$ objects="hello('shubham')"
$ awk -v myvar="$objects" '$0==myvar{f=1} f; $0=="REPLACE"{exit}' a.txt
hello('shubham')
abc
bcd
REPLACE
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing the `pattern`s are unique to the relevant lines, combining the variable in your starting line pattern (using `&&`) with `/hello/` should fix the extra line problem:

```
awk -v myvar="$objects" '($0~myvar && /hello/),/REPLACE/' a.txt
```

output:

```
hello('shubham')
abc
bcd
REPLACE
```

Tested using mawk 1.3.4 on Raspberry Pi 400

Comment: Generally a reasonable approach, but fairly expansive -- it would match a commented-out `hello('shubham')` line in addition to a real/live/uncommented one, f/e. Of course, the OP's original code had that same behavior, so maybe that's what they want.

Answer (score 0):

a generic `awk` solution allowing for partial matches that properly escapes all special characters for all `awk` variants without having to pre-escape them at the shell level :

```
# one of the cleaner ways to pass single-quoted single quotes 
# to awk since the octal codes aren't being interpreted by the shell  

___='??hello(\47sh{}u*[]bh(+)am\47)'
```

> 

```
printf '%s' "other-unwanted-content-here 
             target(shubham)
             ??hello('sh{}u*[]bh(+)am')
             abc
             bcd
             REPLACE
             other-unwanted-content-here" |
```

> ```
> mawk2 -v ___="$___" 'BEGIN { _=(_="\\")_
>
>    gsub("[[-_!-/:-@{-~]", "["(__ = "&")"]",___)
>    gsub("["(_)"^]", (_)__, ___);      FS = ___
>
>    _*=_ } !_<NF, ____==$_' ____='REPLACE'
> ```

```
??hello('sh{}u*[]bh(+)am')
abc
bcd
REPLACE
```

*The pair of `regex`-escaping `gsub()`s escapes more than what's needed because the alternative is a backslash nightmare*